# NextJS 13 Client vs Server Component

Tags: next.js, fetch

I'm trying to build a simple login/register page and I am having issues deciding on whether it should be a client or server component. According to NextJS 13 docs, When you fetch data, it should be a server component and they mention that you should "fetch data where it's used", and when you have interactivity, it should be a client component. Doesn't my register/login page fit both definitions?

When I wrote code in prior versions of NextJS (or React for that matter), I used to have a service folder with an api function making calls to the backend. Does this still apply?

Thanks

Comment: You can have the services/fetching functions anywhere and use it in client or server components. Yes, interactive components should be client components for obvious reasons but what you can do is [move the components that need interactivity to the leaves](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#moving-client-components-to-the-leaves) of the tree to minimize the JavaScript sent to the client (maybe the form, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the difference is interactivity

- Server Components should be used for everything that can be rendered once on the server and not need any kind of interactivity in the browser (no hooks, no javascript once rendered really).
  It can fetch data that needs to be displayed and rendered server-side. The result will be pure HTML/CSS, that can be streamed to your client, and that's awesome
- Client Components on the other hand are meant to be interactive in your browser (useContext, hooks, access browser features, etc). You can use them everywhere, and they can fetch data too if you want, but from the browser)

If you used React before, you've built your app entirelly with Client Components.
Server Components are new and allow you to optimize your network usage (smaller bundle, better loading speed, fewer roundtrips, simpler caching, ...)
Maybe it helps to see them as highly optimized replacement for API GET calls that can directly return a rendered component instead of JSON.

They may seem restrictive though, but they can be mixed together:

- A login page is usually very static in nature, you probably can render the layout statically in a Server Component, maybe even the form if you don't rely on hook to manage its state. One could argue that it can be 100% static (but I won't)
- More realistically, you will have a Server component to render the layout, modal, links and theme, and the form in a Client Component to manage its state and make the API call

Answer (score 0):

Next.js 13 brings a lot of flexibility and optimization opportunities with the introduction of server components, but it also adds complexity to decision-making.

You're absolutely right that the login/register page seems to straddle the line between needing server and client capabilities. Your codes still work if you use them in client components. API calls are still valid and align well with Next.js 13.

The choice between server and client components doesn't have to be binary. The beauty of Next.js 13 is that you can mix server and client components freely. There are some use cases for server components: fetching initial data, showing static content, rendering for SEO... and so on. Take the login/register page for example, you could have the layout as a server component for SEO and initial data fetching benefits, while the form itself could be a client component to handle the interactive elements.

The best way to start is to read the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation).